# Astrisk+SIP+Database

Tags: sip, asterisk

Can I use SIP account from database?

As I understand. I can config SIP account in sip.conf.
But I want to support use many account.

Can I get SIP account from database that I created for dial out instead of sip.conf?
Or Other way I can do it.

Comment: This is not programming related, the question belongs at Serverfault

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is called 'RealTime' in Asterisk (yes, it doesn't make much sense `;)`).

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+RealTime+Sip