# Asterisk-Java sip show peers

Tags: java, asterisk

I use Asterisk 1.8 with Mysql version 5.1.69 (OS : CentOS Release 6.4, istalled in Virtual machine Oracle VM Virtual Box). From Win 7 32bit, I tried to get information about sip peers using this code :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.asteriskjava.manager.ManagerConnection;
import org.asteriskjava.manager.ManagerConnectionFactory;
import org.asteriskjava.manager.action.CommandAction;
import org.asteriskjava.manager.response.CommandResponse;



public class Manager
{
    private ManagerConnection c;

    public Manager() throws Exception
    {
        ManagerConnectionFactory factory = new ManagerConnectionFactory(
                "172.16.213.91", "asterisk", "asterisk");
        c =  factory.createManagerConnection();
    }

    public void run() throws Exception
    {
        c.login();

        CommandAction action;
        CommandResponse response;
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        action = new CommandAction();
        //action.setCommand("core show help");
        action.setCommand(" sip show peers");
        response = (CommandResponse) c.sendAction(action);

        list = response.getResult();
        System.out.println(list.size());
        int i = 0;
        while ( i <list.size())
        {

            System.out.println(list.get(i));
            i++;
        }

        c.logoff();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        new Manager().run();
    }
}
```

I got this output in console :

```
18 avr. 2014 11:01:07 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl connect
INFO: Connecting to 172.16.213.91:5038
18 avr. 2014 11:01:07 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl setProtocolIdentifier
INFO: Connected via Asterisk Call Manager/1.1
18 avr. 2014 11:01:07 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl setProtocolIdentifier
ATTENTION: Unsupported protocol version 'Asterisk Call Manager/1.1'. Use at your own risk.
18 avr. 2014 11:01:07 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl doLogin
INFO: Successfully logged in
18 avr. 2014 11:01:07 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.EventBuilderImpl buildEvent
INFO: No event class registered for event type 'fullybooted', attributes: {status=Fully Booted, event=FullyBooted, privilege=system,all}
18 avr. 2014 11:01:09 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl doLogin
INFO: Determined Asterisk version: Asterisk 1.0
18 avr. 2014 11:01:09 org.asteriskjava.manager.internal.ManagerConnectionImpl disconnect
INFO: Closing socket.
2
Name/username              Host                                    Dyn Forcerport ACL Port     Status     Realtime
0 sip peers [Monitored: 0 online, 0 offline Unmonitored: 0 online, 0 offline]
```

Even, I connected to Asterisk with sip user. I got the same result.

I have 5 users in my Data base.

Could you please help me to get  information about the status of sip peers ( connected or not, ip adress...). I use asterisk-java-0.3.jar in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me. I'm using Asterisk 1.8 Cert and 0.3 jar.

```
INFO: Determined Asterisk version: Asterisk 1.0
6
Name/username              Host                                    Dyn Forcerport ACL Port     Status     
1000                       (Unspecified)                            D   N             0        Unmonitored 
1001                       (Unspecified)                            D   N             0        Unmonitored 
1002                       (Unspecified)                            D   N             0        Unmonitored 
1003                       (Unspecified)                            D   N             0        Unmonitored
```

I would check the manager.conf mine looks like:

```
[manager]
secret=pa55w0rd
permit=0.0.0.0/255.255.255.255
read=all
write=all
```

To rule out the Java api connect to the [AMI](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+manager+API) with telnet directly. Example [here](http://www.jcgonzalez.com/test-asterisk-ami-telnet)

Once you are logged in. To send a cli command use

```
Action: Command
command: sip show peers
```

and press intro twice. Also try to connect locally to the AMI from the machine Asterisk is installed.

**UPDATE**
my manager.conf

```
[general]
enabled = yes
webenabled = yes
port = 5038 
bindaddr = 0.0.0.0 
[asterisk]
secret = asterisk
permit = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
read=all
write=all
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hello, 
 Thanks for replying.But still doesn't work for me. my manager.conf look like this:

    [general]
    enabled = yes
    webenabled = yes
    port = 5038
    bindaddr = 0.0.0.0
[asterisk]
secret = asterisk permit = 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0 read = all,system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,originate write = all,system,call,log,verbose,command,agent,user,originate

                                                                    I will use this class in Java Swing program so I need it.
If you may accept to help me with asterisk, I could upload my Virtual Machine and give you the link.

Comment: try connecting to the ami with a telnet as shown above. Your manager.conf does work for me.

Comment: I executed this command action "database show" from java program, I got this message: Database unavailable But from CLI, I got some information from Data base.

Answer (score 1):

I tried with telnet this command

```
 action: sippeers
 actionid: 4
```

I got this response:

```
Response: Success  
ActionID: 4  
EventList: start  
Message: Peer status list will follow    

Event: PeerlistComplete  
EventList: Complete  
ListItems: 0  
ActionID: 4
```

Like you can see, I got nothings.

Comment: This is not a Java related question but a database configuration problem. Have a look at this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656988/astrisksipdatabase](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656988/astrisksipdatabase). Good luck